# Is it correct to abbreviate etc as &c?

Tags: abbreviations, ampersand, etc

I recently asked someone why they had several instances of "&c" in their writing, to which they told me that &c is another abbreviation for et cetera. I have since looked it up and understand now where this comes from, with the "&" being more than just an "and" symbol, that written correctly it is actually based on, and looks like, "et".

Apparently some people have used it this way before, but "some people have done it, especially in the past" makes it neither correct nor accepted in general. One site I came across in my research on this even states that you should not do this.

> Finally, ‘etc.’ should not be written with an ampersand instead of the
>   ‘et’ part (&c) except when an older source is being duplicated or
>   transcribed.

[That is from a description of when to use etc. from proof-reading-service.com](https://www.proof-reading-service.com/en/blog/two-latin-abbreviations-frequently-used-scholarly-writing-etc-et-al/)

Is "&c" a correct way to abbreviate "et cetera" in English? Or was it a temporary slang term, similar to "aint", but which never caught on and is used to be quaint?

Comment: It is not in current use, but in older writings e.g. 19th century & prior it frequently appears. The modern accepted abbreviation is "etc".

Comment: The correct modern abbreviation is "etc." Note that includes the period indicating an abbreviation. The "&c" abbreviation makes little sense. It's "et cetera", not "and cetera", and "&c" mixes the reference languages.

Comment: @RMac It is my understanding, from the research I had just done, that "&" refers to the Latin "et" rather than the English "and", that we just happen to say "and" because we are speaking English. Whether that is accurate, I'm not sure, but that is what I read. Supposedly, a properly written historical "&" symbol was supposed to resemble a mixture of "e" and "t" together.

Comment: @RMac Whether it "makes little sense or not" - it was certainly in widespread use at one time.

Comment: As we frequently point out, there is no single authority for this kind of thing; matters of style are governed by who you are writing for (e.g. your editor, your thesis advisor, your vice president of marketing, your film censorship board) and who you are writing to (e.g. your grandmother, your Congressman, the recipients of your company newsletter, the voters in the general election). No one can stop you from using &c., and you can't stop anyone from being confused by it, or assuming it's an error, or thinking you're pretentious for it.

Comment: @RMac The ampersand is literally a stylistic variant of the letters _Et_. If anything, it’s using an ampersand to represent the English word _and_ that mixes languages.

Comment: @Aaron There are some typefaces where the 'E' and the 't' components are more obvious.

Comment: There has never been a temporary slang term *aint*. Sometimes it represents a sort of eye-dialect spelling for Andy Taylor's Aint Bea, his mother's sister. :-) Moreover, *ain't* is neither slang nor temporary.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The "ampersand" - so named in the 19th century is a corruption of "and per se - and". *1882   E. A. Freeman in Longman's Mag. 1 95   ‘Ampussy and,’ that is, in full ‘and per se, and,’ is the name of the sign for the conjunction and, &, which used to be printed at the end of the alphabet.* (OED) (This does not contradict your comment, but simply attempts to add to it).

Comment: @WS2 Yes, the language-mixing goes deep enough that even the name befuddles the matter. I do wonder why that lovely variant _ampussy and_ didn’t catch on, though…

Comment: What do you mean by 'aint'? Are you referring to the informal "I ain't" for "I am not"?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, I was attempting in a few words to compare and contrast my (apparently incorrect) understanding of &c with the history of "aint". "Aint" used to be considered incorrect, many people were annoyed by its usage, and one very commonly repeated phrase was "Aint is not in the dictionary." That is, until it was added. So the contrast was where aint was added as a generally accepted part of the language where I was asking if &c was not. Also, I do not add an apostrophe to aint because it is not a proper contraction for most uses of the word. Aint usually aint used as ain't.

Comment: FWIW, it was my usage of ‘&c’ on another SE site that prompted this question.  (Not that I take it personally; it's a perfectly good question!)  I used to use ‘etc.’, but changed over many years ago — the two seemed equally popular and clear, but ‘&c’ has two advantages: 1) it's slightly shorter, and 2) it's more often used without a trailing full stop, which avoids awkwardness, especially before a comma or at the end of a sentence.

Comment: The reference you link saying not to use it is specific to scholarly writing ("professional proofreading services exclusively for professors, lecturers, post-doctoral researchers, research students") and its correct that "&c" isn't appropriate *in that context*...even though it's fine (maybe a little bit unusual) in personal/informal writing.

Comment: @gidds I appreciate you weighing in here with _why_ you do it. That is possibly more useful than technical correctness, but that question (why) would have been closed for being opinionated. My question here was out of curiosity; personally I don't really care as long as communication is clear. That is evident in that I care little about "proper" spelling and consider it a modern nuisance (people used to just spell things out the way they sound; the whole "Shakespeare didn't even write his name the same every time").

Comment: @Aaron How do you mean _ain’t_ isn’t a proper contraction for most uses? Are you referring to its origin as a contraction of _am not_, rather than _are/is not_ (or, even later on, _have/has not_)? Because that doesn’t make it an improper contraction, just a case of one paradigmatic form encroaching on others (which is common enough, cf. the entire 2sg) – the vowel elision itself remains as much an elision as it ever was. If that is indeed the reason, do you also write _dont_ and _werent_ without the apostrophe when used ‘inappropriately’?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't see how using "ain't" for "have not" is in any way correct. I don't understand everything you've said, as English language ruling is not my specialty, but as far as the "a little above laymen's understanding" goes, a contraction is essentially just a couple words mashed together with some letters replaced by an apostrophe. I don't see "have" anywhere in "ain't". If I have time, I may look into what you've said. As for don't/weren't, I don't know of a time when they are used inappropriately. Don't = do not, and weren't = were not; I'm not familiar with other usage.

Comment: @Aaron Oh I see – you were referring to its extension to mean _have/has not_ as well as _am/are/is not_. The point remains, though: the apostrophe represents the elided _o_ in _not_, and that is still elided, regardless of which is the base verb. It’s not regular for any of _am/are/is/have/has_ to become _ai-_, but _not_ to _-n’t_ is the regular pattern. With _don’t_ and _weren’t_, I was referring to their dialectal use to mean _does not_ and _was not_ (_he don’t_, _it weren’t_), which is similar.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I see: you make a good point, and it is taken. Now that you mention it, yes, I have seen "he don't." "he don't" makes me cringe a little, but I would indeed have written it with an apostrophe. "it weren't" goes beyond cringe-worthy; I generally assume anyone saying/writing "It weren't that big." is either extremely poor at speaking English or that they are having a very bad off-day. Still, for similar reasons to what you've stated, the apostrophe is not the problem and still omits the letter. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't call "&c." a slang term, given that even the Oxford English Dictionary used it in 1884; see page xi of [this excerpt from the OED web site](http://public.oed.com/wp-content/uploads/General-Explanations.pdf#page=5) (my emphasis):

> Hence, while the senses are numbered straight on 1, 2, 3, **&c.**, they are also grouped under branches marked I, II, III, **&c.**, in each of which the historical order begins afresh. Subdivisions of the senses, varieties of construction, **&c.**, are marked a, b, c, **&c.**; subdivisions of these, which rarely occur, (a.), (b.), (c.), **&c.**

Typing "&c" as the search term into Google Books produces many more examples of its use in serious text books ([Google Books link](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%26c)).

In its day, it was a normal abbreviation of *etcetera*.  Only more recently has "etc." taken over from it.

Comment: Agreed: it's perfectly reasonable, but can appear dated now.

Answer (score 7):

Eh.... depends?

An [**abbreviation**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abbreviation) is a shortening of something (*a(b) - brevere*; *to make brief*). *Etc.* spelled out is **[et cetera](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/etcetera)**.

*Et cetera* is composed of *et* ("and"; French still retains this form with an unpronounced "t", Spanish drops the final consonant and just has *y*) and *ceter-a*, the plural of *ceter-us*, meaning things (plural) left behind, or remains, perhaps related to the Latin *[cēdere](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cede)* "to go, move away, withdraw, yield."

So we have *etc.*, where the space is dropped and the letters for *cetera* are dropped and represented by a dot *.*

Technically, we have a symbol for "and" and technically *et*=*and*. So, with respect to [transitive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), sure: *&c.*, why not? There is precedent the use of numbers or symbols in abbreviations. Take for example "[W3](https://www.w3.org/)", "[EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)", and neologisms such as "LGBTQ+" .

I would suggest though you leave it as a plain "*etc.*" (dot included). "*&c.*" seems like an [affectation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affectation).

Comment: Nice answer. The last statement on affection feels a bit POB for me. See answer below from @SimonB.

Comment: @ib11 Think of 'affectation' as a synonym of 'outdated, uncommon, only used idiosyncratically nowadays'